# Phonegap Crop selected area

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am using JCrop to crop  the image taken from camera or from gallery the cropping works pretty  well. The  problem i am facing is if the image is too large the  actual image starts scrolling means its height is more than the height of phone .I just want to show  that image i a specified area may be inside a div . i cant  give height and width of a image if  i do so Jcrop plugin not crop the actual area . I don't know how to  manage  the image and cropping at the same time any help or suggestion is  appreciated.

Comment: Jcrop is not working in phonegap from my side. iF you solve this problem than tell me.

Comment: yeah i got Jcrop working...I have implemented a different plugin that fulfill my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why you are using a plugin to crop images. The Camera plugin for Cordova is able to crop images as well. You can use the function like this:

```
function capturePhotoEdit() {
            // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, **allowEdit: true**,
                                        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
        }
```

You can crop the images then while you take a photo.

For your Thumbnail you can use

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData1) {
            imageData = imageData1;
            // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
            // console.log(imageData);

            // Get image handle
            //
            var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

            // Unhide image elements
            //
            smallImage.style.display = 'block';

            // Show the captured photo
            // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
            //
            smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }
```

and

```
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:50px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
```

Okay, you can not directly crop the photo you take, but you can select an area from the image. I think this is nearly the same and it works fine!

Comment: this type of cropping is a different than what i need .may be possible some phone  camera won't allow to edit or crop  the image so  i need a cropper to ensure used will get cropping feature after taking image from camera